# Categorising syntax in Eclipse outline

Tags: rascal

I'm trying to create an outline for a syntax definition I create in rascal. I've managed to make the various object appear in the outline by simply adding label annotations like recommended in the documentation. However, I would also like to "categorise" these objects so that all the objects of the same type end up under a common collapsible category. Like the way that Rascal's outline is with all the annotations, functions, variables, tests and so on sorted into their own categories. I haven't found anything really in the documentation about it. I've tried applying @Category to the syntax and to the AST, neither really worked

```
public node ps_outline(Tree x){
    PSGAME g = ps_implode(x);
    
    return g;
}
```

This is currently the function that I register as my outliner, all that `ps_implode` does is add a @label and @location annotation to the imploded syntax definition.

```
new_l @ location = l@location;
new_l @ label = "Level";
```

Current outline vs Desired outline

[image: The current appearance of the outline]
[image: Desired outline (mockup)]

Comment: By the way, this looks like a cool language!

Comment: I'm trying to parse PuzzleScript to do some code analysis on the games written with that engine, it's a lot of fun :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest nodes like so:

```
"Sounds"(["soundData"(...)])
```

The nesting of the value will be reflected in the outline.
Lists will be treated as elements on the same nesting level.
The intermediate nodes use the same labels and location information. If a node label appears twice I'm not sure what happens.. it could be that the trees under the same nodes are merged 
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try this as soon as I can and report back!

Comment: Finally figured it out, looks great now. I also found looking at the example for [Rascal](https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/rascal/ide/Outline.rsc) very useful. Thanks for your help.

Comment: have a nice day!